# How do I separate "vorziehen" from this sentence?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, phrase-request

How can I say:

> ... but I would rather/would prefer to speak in German

Is the following sentence correct?

> ... aber ich ziehe um Deutsch zu sprechen vor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make it explicit:

The phrase

> ... but I would prefer to speak in German.

translates to

> ..., aber ich ziehe es vor, deutsch zu sprechen.

The additional word *lieber,* as mentioned in the other answer, is wrong in my opinion as you could translate your phrase to

> ..., aber ich würde lieber deutsch sprechen.

which is also correct, but combing the solutions is like filling up your sentences with superfluous words like *actually* or just repeating yourself.

The first solutions seems to be more eloquent and should be preferred in writing, the second solution, however, is what most people would say in a regular conversation.

Answer (score 2):

As already said, it is:

"... aber ich **ziehe es lieber vor**, Deutsch zu sprechen"

Please make sure that the comma isn't missing.

*Please Note:*

"Lieber" is an additional word, so it is not needed in this case.

Comment: So you prefer to prefer to speak German?

Comment: Nein, das wäre dann "ich ziehe es lieber vor, vorzuziehen Deutsch zu sprechen." Und das würde keinen Sinn ergeben, lieber Carsten

Comment: Du meinst nicht, dass der Satz aussagt, dass Du beispielsweise lieber vorziehst, Deutsch zu sprechen, als Englisch zu sprechen vorzuziehen?

Comment: Dein Satz hat einen Grammatikfehler *hust*:

"Du meinst nicht, dass der Satz aussagt, dass Du beispielsweise lieber vorziehst, Deutsch zu sprechen, als Englisch **zu** sprechen vorzuziehen?"

Das "zu" musst Du weglassen, dann ist Dein Satz richtig.
Des Weiteren ist, wie man einsehen kann, die Vorgängerversion meiner Respondierung etwas anders.

Comment: Furthermore, as you noted, *lieber* isn't necessary at all. I recommend removing this entirely, because it's rather distracting from the actual problem.

Comment: I retract my previous statement, saying that the comma is optional (comment already deleted). It's obligatory indeed, because the word "es" is 'announcing' the phrase.